# How to hide specific parameters from url in angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I wanted to hide only parametes `a1` and `b1` from:

```js
this.router.navigate(['/'], {queryParams:{a1:a, b1:b, c1:c, d:d}});
```

Right now the browser url is fetched as

```
https://APP_PATH/?a1=a&b1=b&c1=c&d1=d
```

The url should be shown as below

```
https://APP_PATH/?c1=c&d1=d
```

Tried `skiplocationchange` but it is hiding all parameters.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow, I edited your post to first reformat your code chunk, second to remove sensitive data related to your local path and port, for security reasons you shall never share it publicly, instead you can just replace it by an understandable keyword as `https://APP_PATH/..`

Comment: Answering to your question: you have to be specific: are you asking how to remove the `a1` and `b1` from the query params ? or you want them to pass through the route but hiding it from being visible in the URL of the browser ? both cases are different

Comment: No, I dont want to remove a1 and b1...wanted to hide the parameters.  want those parameters to pass through the route but hiding it from being visible in the URL of the browser

Answer (score 0):

To pass hidden data between components or using the routing system in your case, I would recommend you to work with one of these features/suggestions:

- Either you pass data through the routing system using the `data` property, [check this for more details](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-data-to-route/)
- Either you make a communication tunnel between components using Observables/Subscriptions like `Subject` or `BehaviourSubject`, [check this for more details](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-subject-example/)
- Or, depending on your use case, passing the data through Inputs/Outputs of your components, [check this for more details](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

**Important PS:** when you make a subscription using Subject or BehaviourSubject features, **do never forget** to unsubscribe it from your component, most probably in your `ngOnDestroy(){..}` lifecycle, because it would cause a [memory leak issues](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/preventing-angular-subscription-memory-leaks-65f18eb9cb8e).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar case recently where I wanted to remove query parameters without reloading the site. So I adapted my solution to something similar to yours.

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  queryRead = false;
  a1: any;
  b1: any;
  c1: any;
  d: any;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    setQueryParams();
  }

  setQueryParams(){
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        // If you want to keep the query params
        if (!queryRead) {
          this.a1 = params['a1'];
          this.b1 = params['b1'];
          this.c1 = params['c1'];
          this.d = params['d'];
          queryRead = true;
        }
        // Remove query parameters
        this.router.navigate([], {
          relativeTo: this.route,
          queryParams: null,
          queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
        });
        // Add query parameters
        this.router.navigate([], {
          relativeTo: this.route,
          queryParams: {c1: c1, d1: d1},
          queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
        });
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it's relevant and that I understood your problem correctly.

Edit: Added a check so that the variables aren't overwritten.

Comment: But it wont maintain the state of application.Like if you open same url in different tab you will not get same data

Comment: I dont want to remove a1 and b1 parameters..that is passed to route..wanted to hide it only

Comment: You can always handle logic to put them back if you need them later. If you save them to some variables like in my code example you effectively hide them, but you still have access to them in the code as long as you don't lose the context (like a page reload).
With my example you will end up with this URL: localhost:4200/?c1=c&d1=d
But you will also have the other parameters stored in variables in the code.

Comment: yes that is correct.But I want the state of page..How can you hide it when it is passed to a route this.router.navigate(['/'],{queryParams:{a1:a,b1:b,c1:c,d:d}})

Comment: I'm not sure that what you describe is possible. If you copy the URL and enter it into another window/tab you will have no other information about the state than what is in the query parameters. If you however do some code mainpulation on the full URL you can have a link to click with all the parameters, but once you enter the URL only the 2 desired parameters will be shown once the page is loaded.

Comment: wanted to hide those parameters from browser's url ..it will be passed to route

Comment: If you're talking about navigation within the same page I'd probably delegate the variables to a service or something like that and skip having the variables in the query parameters at all.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to check if the variable is being overwritten with 'undefined'?

Comment: Updated the code slightly

Comment: Weird. Apart from the name and number of parameters, this is the exact code I'm using to store query parameters and manipulate the query string. The state is persisted. Are you using the correct component to handle the route manipulation? It looks to be in the root component, so you are using the app.component.ts?

Comment: Have you tried leaving the first parameter of this.router.navigate as an empty array ([]) instead of ['/']?

Comment: If I open the resulting URL in a different tab the state will not be persisted as the URL does not contain any other information than what is in the URL string.

If you're navigating between different components, that is a different problem. I would try using variables in a parent class or using a service to store the information if you wish to hide the data.